# Check if file exists on another website

Tags: php

I've been trying to develope code that would check if a pdf file exists on another website. For testing purposes, I found a random pdf file online:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf

I tried the following code and neither of the two methods worked:

Method 1:

```
$path1 = 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf';
if (file_exists($path1))
{
  echo "found!";
}
else
{
  echo "not found";
}

//RESULT: not found
```

Method 2:

```
function UR_exists($url){
   $headers=get_headers($url);
   return stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
}

if(UR_exists('http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf'))
   echo "This page exists";
else
   echo "This page does not exist";

//RESULT: This page does not exist
```

The page executes fine in both situations, but the result is always that the file doesn't exist, when I know it exists lol. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- But I am not receiving any errors. The page executes fine, but the result is false in both cases and I don't understand why.

Comment: maybe their site doesn't like to be fetched.

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe, but I tried this with other sites and it was the same result. Also, If I click the link manually, I get directed to the pdf file no problem, so that leads me to believe that there must be a simple way of checking the existence, but now I'm stuck.

Comment: Method 2 worked on my server, `UR_exists` returned `true` for that url. Note that `get_headers()` will return `false` on error (for example couldn't connect to server), you are currently not checking on that. Why it doesn't work on yours? Verify `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` returns `1` (`true`) or maybe a firewall is blocking your request. In both cases `get_headers()` will return false.

Comment: @PetervanderWal This could be the case yes. I'll have to find out how to check if it didn't connect to the server. If you have a recommendation for an if conditional I'll kindly accept as well hahah

Comment: `if ($headers === false) { echo "Could not connect"; return false; }` I guess

Comment: What has this got to do with PDFs? Hint: Nothing

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit lol. when I first created the question I personally didn't know if the file type mattered, so I made the question specific to pdf since that's the file format that mattered to me the most, however it's even better that this seems to work for all file types (that is what I am inferring at least).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file_exists` uses physical paths, the parameter you need to provide should be the address on that server where the file can be found, and not an url!
in the other hand the header method should be working fine! but testing against 404 header response is worth trying and you can do it like so:

```
$url = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf";
$header_response = get_headers($url);
if (header_response) {
    if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "404" ) !== false ){
      // PDF DOES NOT EXIST
        echo "PDF DOES NOT EXIST";
    }else{
      // PDF EXISTS!!
        echo "PDF EXISTS";
    }
}else {
    echo "PDF DOES NOT EXIST";
}
```

please keep in mind that `allow_url_fopen = 1` which allows you to use external URLs should be enabled

Comment: Hi @Med Abida ! I tried out your method on a $url that doesn't exist `$url = 'http://www.asdfasdzzfasdf.com/asd.pdf'` and it is saying that it does exist. Can you confirm that it's the same case for you?

Comment: I also obtain a notice saying: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ....` which refers to the line `if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "404" ) !== false ){`

Comment: The notice is gone now, it was because of the error reporting function I had placed inside the code, however the code still says "file exists" to all pdf files, regardless if they exist or not.

Comment: this is a screen recording that prove that the test did work! http://sendvid.com/gacwhhxj

Comment: I see, I'll check a few things right now to see if they are the problem.

Comment: Don't rely on 404 alone. How about 403's (forbidden), 301 (moved) etc? Verifying a 200-result is in my opinion better than the absence of 404.

Comment: @Webeng it will only return a false result (file exist when its not) only when the url itself isnt valid and im sure that your page is not reporting the error because when i tried `'http://www.asdfasdzzfasdf.com/asd.pdf'` it returns an error and file exist! that can be solved by checking the url is valid or not

Comment: Ohh I see, and it might be a stupid question, but how can I check if the url is valid?

Comment: Don't call `get_headers` twice, as it will do two requests to the server, where only 1 is sufficient. Store the result in a variable, and check if that one is `false` (or not)

Comment: @MedAbida works beautifully, thanks mate! and thank you too Peter!

Comment: @Webeng  as peter pointed out ! using 404 could be tricky if the server response contained 403 or 301 ! but using 200 could not work when there is a redirect ! the best way to be sure that the file exist is to test against content-type ! simply by replacing `$header_response[0]` with `$header_response[4]` and `404` with `pdf`

Comment: awesome, I'll keep that in mind when implementing the code

Comment: `header_response`? where is dollar `$`?